# What is the force in the car when you are moving very fast?

Tags: forces

so I'm curious on what the force on your body is when you are travelling very fast in a car. Your body would be pushed back into your seat. I know that if you are going in a circle, there is a imaginary force called the centrifugal force. Is it the called the same in this scenario, where the person isn't moving in a circle?

Comment: Your question illustrates a common misconception in physics.  Once a body is moving at a constant velocity (e.g., constant speed in a straight line), it doesn't take any net force to keep it moving at that velocity.

Answer (score 3):

This fictitious force, or pseudo-force, is (close to) what we would call an [Euler force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_force).

There are two well-known pseudo-forces in circular motion:

- In uniform circular motion the **centrifugal force** is what we call the radial (outwards) pushing tendency.
- In non-uniform circular motion, there is both an radial pushing tendency as well a tangential pushing tendency (pushing you back in the seat). This tangential tendency is what we call an **Euler force**.

When we are only moving straight with no turning, then we might imagine the path as an infinitely large circle and thus still choose to call it an Euler force. There is no other official name for it, as far as I know.

Remember that all these pseudo-forces *only exist in an accelerated frame*. When the object is moving at constant velocity then they do *not* appear anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

"so I'm curious on what the force on your body is when you are travelling very fast in a car"

The laws of motion are the same in all inertial frames i.e. frames moving at a constant velocity. As a consequence, there's no experiment you can do in such a frame to determine if you are moving relative to some other frame of reference. No cheating by looking out the window. ;-)  You don't feel the force you are asking about when you move at constant velocity.

The force you are referring to is only felt when you accelerate. From the point of view of someone on the road (assumed to be an inertial frame), the car seat is accelerating and exerting an unbalanced force on you so you accelerate. But let's view it from your frame of reference in the car where you don't know you're accelerating (again, no cheating). But all of a sudden you are moving toward the back of the seat with a force equal to your mass times the acceleration of the car. This is called a fictitious force because there's no actual force pushing you back it's just a result of analyzing the situation in the accelerating frame of reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are moving in a circle the force is very real, your velocity is changing (remember velocity is a vector so even if its magnitude is constant its direction is changing), and so there is an acceleration perpendicular to your direction of motion, that is why when your car makes a sharp turn you feel "pushed" to the side.

If you are interested in where this force comes from it is the friction with the ground, that is why you cannot make sharp turns on ice.

When your car is accelerating (speed up or slow down) your velocity is also changing, and hence you feel a "push" forward or backward; this is also because of the force which is accelerating you.

But when you are just moving really fast...there is no force, or at least there is an equilibrium (no net force). As a consequence when you are traveling in a slow car, or on the highway or on an airplane your body feels normal; but if a plane/car/boat is speeding up or slowing down, you forsure feel that.

Think about if you were blindfolded in a car on a highway, ideally you wouldnt know if the car is stopped or travelling at 100km/h

Answer (score 1):

Force is related to mass and acceleration, as in

$$
F = m \cdot a
$$

whereas acceleration is actually velocity difference (derivative)

$$
a = \frac{dv}{dt}
$$

As long as there is some velocity change, you will "feel the force". Since velocity is a vector, i.e. it is described with **amplitude and direction**, there will be an acceleration if any of these two change.

For example, if you accelerate from $0~\text{ms}^{-1}$ to $100~\text{ms}^{-1}$ with $a = 10 ~ \text{ms}^{-2}$, and then you maintain constant velocity at $100~\text{ms}^{-1}$, you will feel the force (acceleration) only up until you reach final velocity. Once at $100~\text{ms}^{-1}$ **you will not be "feeling the force"** because $dv = 0$ at that point.

Another interesting example is free fall. If there was not for air resistance, your velocity would be constantly increasing while in free fall due to constant acceleration of $g=9.81~\text{ms}^{-2}$. However, air gives some resistance which heavily depends on your geometry and velocity. Once these two forces become equal, i.e. gravitational pulling you down and air resistance "pushing you back", you will stop accelerating and maintain the constant velocity.

Answer (score 1):

What you are feeling when braking, accelerating or hard cornering is all a result of your inertia, or resistance to a change in the direction or magnitude of your velocity per Newton's first law.

If you were driving at constant speed in a straight line and suddenly accelerated the car, you would feel pushed backward. If you suddenly applied the brakes you would feel pushed forward. When you turn a corner and feel you are being pushed sideways (centrifugal force) it's your body's resistance to a change in direction from a straight line to a curved path.

In each of these cases the "force" you think is either making you go backwards, forwards, or to the side, is not the result of something actually physical contacting your body. Instead it's the result of your being in an accelerating (non-inertial) reference frame.

On the other hand, the forces that actually prevent you from moving forward (your seat belt), backwards (the back of your seat) or to the side (friction of your seat- i.e., the centripetal force) are real.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force
I think that this will answer your question. Usually it can't be described with the instruments you use in inertial frame of reference.